# Can't iterate over multiprocessing.pool.IMapIterator object

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator, multiprocessing

Not sure if it is relevant, but I use Spyder(version 3.3.3) as Python IDE and this python version is 3.7.3

The following is my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

from itertools import product

def func1(a_tup):
    return (a_tup[0][0], *a_tup[1]), (a_tup[0][1]+a_tup[1][0])*a_tup[1][1]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    lst1 = np.arange(4)
    lst2 = np.arange(2, 8, 3)
    lst3 = product(enumerate(lst2),
                      (item for item in product(lst1, lst1) if item[0] < item[1])
                      )

    result1 = np.zeros((len(lst2), len(lst1) -1, len(lst1)), dtype = np.float32)

    with mp.Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1) as pool:
        mp_result1 = pool.imap(func1, lst3)#<--this line right here

    for item in mp_result1:
        print(item)
```

The problem is that as soon as I run this code, it will just sit there and never finish.

I have found that as soon as I change the line `mp_result1 = pool.imap(func1, lst3)` to `mp_result1 = list(pool.imap(func1, lst3))`, the coded will run perfectly. But the thing is, I am looking for a way to make the code work without converting `mp_result1` to a list, because when the generator `mp_result1` becomes big enough in terms of memory usage, converting it to a list object will instantly consume all of the available memory which makes the system freezes. So it is definitely not an ideal situation to be in.

---

So here is my question:

How to iterate over the result of `pool.imap` without converting it to a list object first?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try moving the `for` loop into the `with` block - it doesn't make sense to try to use `mp_result1` after the Pool processes have been killed (which exiting the Pool context manager will do).

Comment: That literally solved my problem. It is weird to me because when the line was `mp_result1 = list(pool.imap(func1, lst3))`, taking the loop outside won't make the script nonrunnable.

Comment: So long as the `list(...)` line was _in_ the `with` block, that's expected.  The list is fully created then before the `with` block exits (and kills the Pool processes on its way out).

Comment: I see... Thank you for your response. I wonder if there is anywhere to look up to about these sorts of behaviors in multiprocessing though.

Comment: Alas, there is no useful generalization of "these sorts of behaviors" to be looked up - the only thing you can really do is ask about the _specific_ behavior that's puzzling you at the time ;-)  Parallel processomg is chock full of subtleties, even at the high level of the `multiprocessing` package.

Comment: I am in the middle of the process of converting a `starmap` operation to an `imap_unordered` opeation, and am tackling the difficulties one by one, because, just like this case, they behave quite a bit differently.